# Word meaning "un-decorate"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a verb that means to remove decoration from a room, in the sense of taking paintings off walls or removing furniture. I would prefer a word that has negative connotations.

I though of "redecorate", but redecorating involves adding new decoration and sounds too positive.

Comment: Strip the room? Strip the room of its contents?

Comment: -1 No research effort shown.

Comment: @ΜετάEd: If you didn't know the word, it's not obvious to me how you'd track it down. Apart from *remove* (which probably wouldn't include *strip* in any dictionary definition), what could OP search for?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Antonyms for "decorate": I quickly turned up "strip" at *Thesaurus.com* under the result "garnish" with "decrease, divest, harm, hurt, leave plain". And OP could have tried synonyms for "remove" and "redecorate". If nothing turned up, OP still should say so. From *[How to Ask](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)*: "Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer".

Comment: Maybe you should just use "undecorate." It seems to be a trend in interior decorating, though I don't think it's got a negative connotation. http://wordspy.com/words/undecorating.asp *Gutting* a room implies removing drywall or plaster and any fixtures; taking it down to the framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd [strip](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22strip%20the%20room%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) the room, house, or whatever (that's 839 written instances of **"strip the room"**).

OED **strip** *To unclothe, denude ... To denude or divest (a thing) of attributes ... To take as plunder or spoil. (Obs.)*

I'm not convinced about that *Obs.* I think if a burglar had enough time (while you were away on holiday, say), then with a van, he could easily *strip* your house of everything of value.

You might also strip the house if you're moving out following a sale that didn't go well. If you'd only recently put up some expensive curtains, say, that the buyers didn't want to pay extra for, you might take them even if they're not going to be any use in your new place.

Of course, if OP wants to sound *really* "negative, he could always say he...

> [**gutted** the place](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22gutted%20the%20place%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) before he left.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered something like *disfigure* or *deface*?